# How to create Wallet for Private Blockchain Network?

Tags: private-blockchain, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I am creating private block chain network on AWS. Can I use existing block chain wallets like MyEth wallet with Private network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use MyEtherWallet with private blockchain. From MyEtherWallet you can choose the RPC server the wallet has to connect to. Choose Add Custom Node  and provide the URL corresponding to your private node/RPC service.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But in that case Every person who will want to connect with our network must be trained with this?

Comment: I guess so. Its not too much of a training anyway. Just one helpfile on how to do it.